# Mocking local object of a method and reading from it

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I am using powermckito and trying to mock a local object and read a API from it. My implementation class is as below:

```
public class LogoutUtil {

    public static void updateState() {
        SrvcContext sc  = new SrvcContext();
        sc.setUserName("UserNAME");

    }
}
```

I am trying to mock the SrvcContext object and read the user name by calling getter.
Here is my test code:

```
@Test
public void updateStateTest() {
    SrvcContext svc = PowerMockito.mock(SrvcContext.class);
    LogoutUtil.updateState();
    try {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(SrvcContext.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(svc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String userName = svc.getUserName(); //This gives null
    Assert.assertEquals("UserNAME", userName);
}
```

Any help how to do it. I cant change the LogoutUtil class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the method `LogoutUtil.updateState` is static and testing and mocking static methods is not always straightforward.
But with PowerMockito you can do it by calling `mockStatic` method: have a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock#methods): it should solve your issue

Comment: HI, If I mock the LogoutUtil as PwerMockito.mockStatic(LogoutUtil.class) then i cant invoke updateState. My problem is I am able to invoke updateState(). The updateState creates internally a SrvcContext object and set. I am trying to get it. I mocked the SrvcContext., but still not able to get from this object.

Comment: I tried this to get the object lke this, but not happening. PowerMockito.whenNew(SrvcContext.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(svc);

Comment: I see that in LogoutUtil.updateState() it is created an instance of SrvcContext, which is destroyed once updateState() has finished execution, and no value is returned. Basically it should happen nothing when you call updateState(): it is istantiated a SrvcContext, is populated with "UserName" and then it is destroyed without being persisted or returned anywhere. I know that you cannot edit LogoutUtil but don't you need that instance of SrvcContext to be returned? As it written, basically nothing happens when you call updateState()